# MySQL aggregate functions with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate-functions

It's Friday afternoon<sup>*</sup> and my brain has stopped working. Normally it is me who's answering dumb SQL questions like this, sorry!

I am trying to get one table, along with the highest value of a column of another table by LEFT JOINing the latter to the former.

```
SELECT
  jobs.*,
  MAX(notes.`timestamp`) AS complete_date
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN notes ON (jobs.id=notes.job_id)
WHERE (jobs.status="complete" OR jobs.status="closed")
  AND (notes.type="complete" OR notes.type IS NULL)
GROUP BY jobs.id
ORDER BY complete_date ASC
```

I am trying to get *all* jobs that meet the `WHERE jobs.`… criteria, and if they have one, the timestamp of the latest `type=complete` note associated with that job:

```
Job ID     Complete Date
1          today
2          NULL
4          yesterday
```

Job 3 don't appear because it don't meet the `jobs.status` criteria. But what I actually get is:

```
Job ID     Complete Date
1          today
4          yesterday
```

Job 2 is missing, i.e. the JOIN is acting like an INNER JOIN.
I am sure it's just me having a brain-dead moment, but I can't see why my LEFT (OUTER) JOIN is not giving me all jobs regardless of the value of the note.

Specifically, users can delete notes, so potentially a complete/closed job may not have a `type=complete` note on it (the notes are entered when the status is changed), I am trying to catch the case when a user closes a job, adds a note, then deletes the note.

<sub>* somewhere in the east</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you have the filter for the `notes` table in the `WHERE` clause the `JOIN` is acting like an `INNER JOIN`, move it to the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT
  jobs.*,
  MAX(notes.`timestamp`) AS complete_date
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN notes 
  ON (jobs.id=notes.job_id)
  AND (notes.type="complete" OR notes.type IS NULL)
WHERE (jobs.status="complete" OR jobs.status="closed")
GROUP BY jobs.id
ORDER BY complete_date ASC;
```

This could also be done using a subquery, so you apply the notes filter inside the subquery:

```
SELECT
  jobs.*,
  n.complete_date
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN
(
    select job_id, MAX(`timestamp`) AS complete_date
    from notes 
    where (type="complete" OR type IS NULL)
    group by job_id
) n
  ON (jobs.id=n.job_id)
WHERE (jobs.status="complete" OR jobs.status="closed")
ORDER BY complete_date ASC
```

Comment: The first half was what I was missing - brain couldn't see what was in front of my eyes, but I have realised the query will need to be more complicated and I won't be able to avoid a subquery. It was written as a subquery an hour ago (still not working). Oh well, swings and roundabouts.

Comment: Moving condition from `WHERE` clause to `JOIN` solved my problem in **SQL Server**. Thanks @Taryn