# Laravel - using sum() with groupBy() does not return groupBy column with null value

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get sum of amounts group by time_ids. I am passing the following time_ids as an array.

Eloquent query is as follows

```php
$time_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$amount = Data::selectRaw('ifnull(sum(amount),0) as amount')
    ->whereIn('time_ids', $time_ids)
    ->groupBy('time_ids')
    ->pluck('amount')
    ->toArray();
```

As a result I get an array of only 3 values.

In my database, time_ids = 1 will not have any value, but I want the query to return 0 if it could not find any value.

Comment: this is a left join scenario.  get all records from one table along with the (sum of) records in another table matching some condition.

Comment: @Erich, I have tried using left join but got the same result. My query is as follows. `Data::selectRaw('ifnull(sum(b.amount),0) as new_amount')->leftJoin('data as b', 'data.id', '=', 'b.id')->whereIn('data.time_ids',$time_ids)->groupBy('data.time_ids')->pluck('new_amount')->toArray();`

Comment: what does your query with `->toSql()` at the end produce?  compare it to the accepted answer in a similar question, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129785/4468423

Comment: @ahu-son your table data should contain the row with `time_ids = 1 ` then it will return the result as you expect.. :)

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya, I would like the result to have time_ids 1 (i.e. all the time ids I pass) and the corresponding sum as 0 even if the database does not have any value of that particular time_id. Is there any other approach I can try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation so adding it as an answer. Your query looks fine to me. Try querying the database directly and see what it is returning. Use this to generate the raw sql

```
$amount = Data::selectRaw('ifnull(sum(amount),0) as amount')->whereIn('time_ids',$time_ids)->groupBy('time_ids')->toSql();
```